# How to get the output of a stored procedure?

Tags: c#

I was wondering how to get the output of a stored procedure without doing it the long way, the long way I am referring to is..

```
SqlParameter productidparam;
productidParam = cmAddProduct.Parameters.Add("@TheProductID", SqlDbType.Int);
productidParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
```

instead I am trying to get the output with overloading like this...

```
cm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@TheProductID", SqlDbType.Int)).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
```

with the long way I know I can get the proc output with

```
string myproductidparam;
myproductidparam = productidparam.Value.ToString();
```

but how do I get the output with the shorter statement?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could pull the parameter from the command by name:

```
myproductidparam = Convert.ToInt32(cm.Parameters["@TheProductID"].Value);
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think it would have been that easy. The more I look at your answer the more I realize how obvious it is. I am so happy to know how it is done, saves me from having to write a lot of unnecessary code. Thanks again, you saved me a lot of time.